# Horizontal and vertical centering of content (I don't understand one thing)

Tags: flexbox

I am on my first steps on using Flexbox. I have done this here: http://goo.gl/fPbdhZ

How can I move the image title below the image?

```
<div class="flexbox-container">
    <div class="flexbox-child">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x400"><br>
        <h4>This title should go below the image</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="flexbox-child">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x400">
        <h4>This title should go below the image</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="flexbox-child">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
        <h4>This title should go below the image</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="flexbox-container">
    <div class="flexbox-child">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x350">
    </div>
    <div class="flexbox-child">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.flexbox-container {
    height: 50%;
    padding: 15px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    .flexbox-child {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0 15px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        img {
            max-height: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the `h4` and `img` elements are side-by-side is that you've set their parent element (`.flexbox-child`) to have `display:flex`.

`display:flex` enables the flexbox layout system, but it also turns on a bunch of defaults for various other flexbox-related properties. In this case, the behavior you're seeing is caused by the default of `flex-direction`, which is `flex-direction: row`, which causes elements to be displayed side by side, instead of on top of each other. `flex-direction` sets the main axis/direction that elements within the flexbox container will flow. You can do left to right, right to left, up or down. CSS Tricks has a [pretty great guide to all things flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) if you'd like to learn more.

So all you need to do is override the default value for flex-direction. In this case, its as simple as setting `flex-direction:column;` on `.flexbox-child`. [Example here](http://codepen.io/nerdgrass/pen/WQbzXX). Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, you're a star!